How to set a quota on Logical Disk Space (logicalused) in ZFS?
I am currently using ZFS and need to set a quota on the logical disk space (logicalused) rather than the physical disk space used after compression. The quota and refquota properties in ZFS set a limit based on the physical space, not on the logical space.
For example, I have dataset with quota and refquota set to 120M.
When I try to fill it with the files, I get result:
# zfs list -o name,quota,used,logicalused,compressratio,referenced,logicalreferenced storage/datatest
NAME                      QUOTA   USED  LUSED  RATIO     REFER  LREFER
storage/datatest           120M   120M   147M  1.68x      120M    147M

But I want to get something like that:
NAME                      QUOTA   USED  LUSED  RATIO     REFER  LREFER
storage/datatest           120M    XXX   120M  1.68x       XXX    120M

Is there a way to set a quota in ZFS that limits the amount of logical space used, i.e. the space used before any compression or deduplication?
Thank you in advance for any insights or suggestions!

Interesting use case. ZFS does not have a mechanism for this. However, can you help explain why you need the physical space quota?

@ewwhite, I need logical disk space quota rather than the physical disk space quota. This is for users' home directories, each of them must have given logical space. Don't ask me why, I don't know myself: my boss told me to redo it this way from the physical quota.

@IvanOlshansky I need logical disk space quota rather than the physical disk space quota. Offhand, I don't know of any filesystem that implements that unless you want to spend large amounts of money for something like a Netapp server.  And even then you might not get it - IBM's top-end GPFS doesn't support it, for example.

@AndrewHenle, It seems to me that it would not be too difficult to implement such an option in ZFS (although, of course, I may be mistaken). It is sad if it is not implemented.
